# leaflet multiple markers json

Tags: laravel, vue.js, leaflet

I use Vue2Leaflet to draw map in vuejs. I need multiple markers in map. From laravel i have this:

```
{
    "successgps": [
        {
            "technicianlocation": "48.8197017,20.3561233"
        },
        {
            "technicianlocation": "48.4623432,19.972569"
        },
        {
            "technicianlocation": "48.259427,19.6557401"
        },
        {
            "technicianlocation": "48.5206828,19.8217017"
        },
        {
            "technicianlocation": "48.8212175,20.3633202"
        }
    ]
}
```

in vue2leaflet I have:

```
    <l-map
      :zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      :options="mapOptions"
      style="height: 80%"
      @update:center="centerUpdate"
      @update:zoom="zoomUpdate"
    >
      <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution" />
      <l-circle-marker
        v-for="(item, index) in markers"
        :key="'marker-' + index"
        :lat-lng="item.technicianlocation"
      ></l-circle-marker>
    </l-map>

axios
        .get("http://api/api/v1/successgps")
        .then(response => {
          this.markers = response.data.successgps;
        });
```

But i think leaflet need this format:

```
      markers: [
        { technicianlocation: latLng(48.8197017, 20.3561233) },
        { technicianlocation: latLng(48.8597017, 20.34561233) }
      ],
```

How to convert data to this format ?

Answer (score 0):

> - LMarker properties accepts latLng: object | array, just use a traversal method to build required format.

> To solve your specific problem use the following snippet in your api request:

```
axios.get('http://api/api/v1/successgps').then((response) => {
  // this.markers = response.data.successgps;
  // var technicianlocation = '48.5206828,19.8217017';
  // console.log(technicianlocation.split(',')[0]);
  response.data.successgps.forEach((element) => {
    this.markers.push({
      technicianlocation: [element.technicianlocation.split(',')[0], element.technicianlocation.split(',')[1]],
    });
  });
});
```

> - You can find in the official VueLeaflet documentation: https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/components/LCircleMarker.html#props